# mysqli insert POST values via array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli, insert

I am trying to get 100+ input fields inserted into my database via an array. The main issue (and yes, I know this is not the safest way of doing this and this is still a work in progress) seems to be that when the array is inserted in the SQL statement, there is an extra "," at the end of the VALUES() section, but no more variable to be placed.

In short, I would need a way to not place anymore "," after the last POST variable has been inserted. Any recommendations on how to go about this?

Thanks

```
//DB setting
include '../../../plugins/MySQL/connect_db.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    $_SESSION["error"] = "DB Connection failed...";     //Error Message 
}

// clear variables
$querystring1 = ""; $querystring2 = "";

foreach($_POST as $key => $var) {
    $querystring2 .= "'".$var."',"; $querystring1 .= $key.",";
}   
$query1 = "(".$querystring1.") VALUES (".$querystring2.")";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `qci_modreport` $query1";

print $sql;

if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "
        <div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissible\">
            <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class=\"icon fa fa-ban\"></i> Error!</h4>
            There was an error while excuting this query.<br />
            (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error . "
          </div>";
} else {

    echo "
        <div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissible\">
            <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class=\"icon fa fa-check\"></i> Alert!</h4>
            Success, record updated successfully. Refreshing database now...
        </div>";
    }

//close connection
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Yes its duplicate but still would like to post this comment. you can add $querystring1 = rtrim($querystring1,',');
    $querystring2 = rtrim($querystring2,','); after complete foreach loop. it will have your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if is the first key for set the $query vars else add the others value

```
  $querystring2 = "";
  $querystring1 "";

  foreach($_POST as $key => $var) {
      if (querystring2 == "" ) {
           $querystring2 .= "'" . $var ;
          $querystring1 .= $key ;
      } else  {
      $querystring2 .= ",'".$var."'"; 
      $querystring1 .= ","$key ;

      }
  }
```